# Record Update form causing Internal Server Error

Tags: php, mysql, dreamweaver

Helo there...

I inserted an Update Record form in Dreamweaver to update the category data on MySQL.
The line of coding below is what is giving me the problem.

```
    <?php echo htmlentities($row_categoryedit['strdiscription'], ENT_COMPAT, 'uft-8'); ?>
```

If it is included the page gives me an internal server error.
If it is excluded the page works, but it dose not update the record.

Also when I preview it live it shows that there is errors on these 2 lines...

```
    if (isset()) {
    $varCategory_categoryedit = ;
```

Am I missing something or doing something wrong?

Comment: `isset()` needs a parameter to be passed to it. http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Comment: `isset(<what to check>)`

Comment: I edited the question as i found which part of the form was causing the internal server error. It is one line of code that i don't know how to fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must have a variable in `isset()` function.

example:

```
if(!isset($varCategory_categoryedit)){ 
  $varCategory_categoryedit = "1"; 
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Comment: Ok i got that in and it took the errors out of the lines, but it is still giving me an internal server error. I also have to discover dynamic files that gives the same error everytime i load the form in. as soon as i take the form out the page works fine.

Comment: I edited the question as i found which part of the form was causing the internal server error. It is one line of code that i don't know how to fix.

Comment: try to change utf-8 to UTF-8 all capital letters. if it doesn't work, please share all your codes

Comment: I fixed the problem above... This Question has been put on hold because i put all my code in, so I had to edit... I now have a new problem that i will ask in 2 days when my hold has been removed.